# Compressing sequence file in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to save RDD as compressed Sequence file. I'm able to save non-compressed file be calling:

```
counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output)
```

where counts is my RDD (IntWritable, Text). However, I didn't manage to compress output. I tried several configurations and always got exception:

```
counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec])
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec])
 required: Option[Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec]]
              counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec])

 counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec])
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec](classOf[org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec])
 required: Option[Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec]]
              counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec])
```

and it doesn't work even for Gzip:

```
 counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
 required: Option[Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec]]
              counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
```

Could you please suggest solution? also, I didn't find how is it possible to specify compression parameters (i.e. compression type for Snappy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature of `saveAsSequenceFile` is `def saveAsSequenceFile(path: String, codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = None)`. You need to send a `Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]]` as `codec`. E.g.,

```
counts.saveAsSequenceFile(output, Some(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec]))
```

If you read the error information of `type mismatch` carefully, you should have corrected it by yourself.