# Spark compile error of rdd.saveAsSequenceFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark

the error message looks like:

```
error: type mismatch; 
[INFO]  found   :Some[Class[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec]]
[INFO]  required: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration [INFO]    
rdd.saveAsSequenceFile(dstPath, Some(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec]))
```

the code looks like:

> rdd.saveAsSequenceFile(dstPath,Some(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec]))

and the rdd type is rdd: RDD[(Text, BytesWritable)]

Comment: I looks up saveAsSequenceFile, the signature is def saveAsSequenceFile(
      path: String,
      codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = None): Unit = self.withScope {
    def anyToWritable[U <% Writable](u: U): Writable = u

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814960/compressing-sequence-file-in-spark